# How to set different paginate_by depending on different requests?

Tags: django

I'm using Django pagination so that I can do view more thing in my website. The below code snippet is what I tried. The page first shows up it shows 7 articles and then shows 6 articles per each view more button clicked.

The below way didn't work. How can I set different `paginate_by` values?

**views.py**

```
class ArticleListView(ListView):
    model = Article
    paginate_by = 7

    def get_template_names(self):
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            self.paginate_by = 6
            return ['blogs/components/articles.html']
        return ['blogs/index.html']
```

**UPDATE**

I tried the `get_paginate_by`, but as it changes `paginate_by` in the middle, the 7th item from the first request shows up as the first item on the second request, meaning that I get 2 duplicate items. I think it's because the item order number changed in the middle.

```
def get_paginate_by(self, queryset):
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            self.paginate_by = 6
        return self.paginate_by
```

Comment: `return self.paginate_by.per` does this line work, or should it be `return self.paginate_by`?

Comment: yes you are right with the duplicates, and what did you want?

Comment: @ruddra Sorry, `per` was a typo. It was supposed to be `self.paginate_by` and still not working